# Android Studio error while opening AVD manager

Tags: android, react-native, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm getting this error all the time:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'project' of com/android/tools/idea/avdmanager/AccelerationErrorNotificationPanel.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AccelerationErrorNotificationPanel.$$$reportNull$$$0(AccelerationErrorNotificationPanel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AccelerationErrorNotificationPanel.<init>(AccelerationErrorNotificationPanel.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdDisplayList.refreshErrorCheck(AvdDisplayList.java:517)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdDisplayList.refreshAvds(AvdDisplayList.java:218)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdDisplayList.<init>(AvdDisplayList.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdListDialog.<init>(AvdListDialog.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.RunAndroidAvdManagerAction.openAvdManager(RunAndroidAvdManagerAction.java:55)
    at org.jetbrains.android.actions.RunAndroidAvdManagerAction.actionPerformed(RunAndroidAvdManagerAction.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$FlatWelcomeScreen$IconsFreeActionGroup$1.actionPerformed(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:742)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:255)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:272)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:203)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:191)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.lambda$onChosen$2(ActionPopupStep.java:185)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:195)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.lambda$dispose$8(AbstractPopup.java:1417)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:3094)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.ifFocusEventsInTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:189)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.executeWhenAllFocusEventsLeftTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.dispose(AbstractPopup.java:1411)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.dispose(WizardPopup.java:160)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.dispose(ListPopupImpl.java:307)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.dispose(PopupFactoryImpl.java:289)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectNode$1.execute(ObjectNode.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectNode$1.execute(ObjectNode.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeActionWithRecursiveGuard(ObjectTree.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectNode.execute(ObjectNode.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:125)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.disposeAllParents(WizardPopup.java:263)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleNextStep(ListPopupImpl.java:442)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl._handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:396)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:342)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.handleSelect(PopupFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased(ListPopupImpl.java:501)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyList.processMouseEvent(ListPopupImpl.java:552)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I tried to delete android files from Home, also `avd` folder from Android folder but nothing helps. I can't find many cases with this error on the internet. Maybe I need to install something else to make it work.

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634082/how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu) tutorial and React Native Getting started tutorial

Comment: This issue is reported as a bug on Google Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128271323 . Star the issue to let the dev team know you're affected.

Answer (score 1):

The solution found in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128271323 (Comments 8 and 14):

Install support to KVM virtualization and set the proper user permissions.

Use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils
sudo usermod -aG kvm $USER
```

And then, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue. And it was fixed when I update the Android Studio to 3.4

Comment: I would consider this as a comment, not an answer.